# How to display WordPress category meta fields on the single post page?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to display custom category meta fields (stored in `wp_options` table) on the single post page (single.php).

I have this code which doesn't work on the single post page (single.php):

```
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
$cat_data = get_option("category_$cat_id");
echo $cat_data['custom_field'];
```

This works only on the `category.php/archive.php` page but not on the single post page (single.php). The post belongs to only one category and I need custom fields of that category without using any plugins.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what about `get_post_meta` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your answer (if you do with wordpress code):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_keys